# Training model in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, linear-regression, sequential

I'm training a neural network using Tensorflow/Keras, ***X_train=(627,24)***, ***Y_train=(627,102)***.
For test ***X_dev=(157,24)***, ***Y_dev=(157,102)***. I used the Sequential model:

```
import tensorflow
model = tensorflow.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tensorflow.keras.Input(shape=(24)))
model.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(102, activation='sigmoid'))
print(model.output_shape)
print(model.compute_output_signature)

model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_percentage_error', optimizer='SGD', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=64, batch_size=32, verbose=0)

loss,accuracy=model.evaluate(X_dev, Y_dev, verbose=0)
print('Model Loss: %.2f, Accuracy: %.2f' % ((loss*100),(accuracy*100)))

import csv
predictions=model.predict(X_dev)
for i in predictions:
    with open('restoredPavia.csv', 'a') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(np.round(i, 0))
```

[image: structure of the NN]

The problem is that I can't obtain an accuracy of more than **3%** and the output I get is either 0 or 1. But ***Y*** should vary in the positive range (1000, 500, 2000 etc.) Because ***X*** data varies in those ranges. I used simple **Linear Regression** before for this problem and I obtained good results. But I'm required to develop NN to predict the output.
What is wrong with this approach? Can it be fixed? Or NN is not suitable for this problem. Please, let me know if you need more information. Maybe I should change the output of the sigmoid function to convert 0 and 1 to a wide range? Maybe I should provide the model with more data.

Comment: You are doing regression and accuracy is a classification metric, so using this metric does not make any sense.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy  I see, I'm a very beginner at this. Can you please, give details or directions? what should I use in this case? What changes I should make?

Comment: I already did, do not use accuracy, you do not need any metric, they are not strictly required.